# How to boot into Ubuntu after installing into a pre-installed Windows 8 pc?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, windows-8

I recently just installed Ubuntu 13 from a USB drive.
I have/had Windows 8 64 bit on my desktop computer.

When I restart and boot my computer, there is not an option that allows me to choose Ubuntu, it goes straight to Windows 8. I understand this is a common issue.

However, my main question is, how do I get to even GO INTO Ubuntu after it's installed? 
I don't mind booting into Windows 8 at first, but how can I even choose to see Ubuntu now that it's installed?

Answer (score 1):

1.Log in into your windows 8 os.Download and install EasyBCD from [*`here`*.](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/EasyBCD-Download-45820.html)

2.Under linux section add a boot entry for your Ubuntu Partition.
And also add entry for your windows 8 partition.

3.reboot

Or

try [`boot-repair disk`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/) .